# How to implement global exception handling as done in angular JS using native javaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to object oriented javaScript programming.
How to implement a global level exception handling module in javaScript.

For eg. suppose I have a .js file. I want to handle any exception coming out of my 
java script file by a common function say exceptionHandlingFunc.

consider angular.js expection handling system for any exception a proper expection is thrown in console.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror